# Run interdependent custom tasks only once with grunt.registerTask

Tags: gruntjs

Is there an option in Grunt where I can easily skip the already called interdependent tasks internally?

For example in this Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('testTask', function () {
    console.log('echo from testTask');
  });
  grunt.registerTask('testBundle', [
    'testTask'
  ]);
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'testTask',
    'testBundle'
  ]);
};
```

assume that I can't change `testBundle` task.

Calling `grunt` will output `echo from testTask` twice, and I need the `default` task to skip running `testTask` again.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?